# seeds.txt and usage.txt not generated for Proguard with Android Studio release build

Tags: android, proguard, spongycastle

I am building my Android app release build by enabling `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources`. I am using a library named `spongycastle` for cryptographic purposes. The problem I am facing is that the entire spongycastle code is being bundled with the apk even if I am using a small part of it. I am not sure which internal library has mentioned the keep rules for it. I tried looking for `seeds.txt` and `usage.txt` in my build output but only found `mappings.txt` and `resources.txt` files. Can someone point out what might be the reason for this?

**Also, is there any other better way to debug this?**

Answer (score 0):

Check if the proguard.txt of the spongycastle library contains '-dontshrink'